# I have a slideshow working to change the images, however how do i add a seperate html page link to each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var index=0;
var titles=[1,2,3,4];

function moveToNextSlide()
{
if (index >= 4){index=0}
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideName="images/img" + titles[++index] + ".jpg";
img.src=slideName;
}

function moveToPreviousSlide()
{
    if (index <= 0){index=4}
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("img1");
        var slideName="images/img" + titles[--index] + ".jpg";
        img.src=slideName;
    }
}
```

That is the javascript code for my slideshow and in my html I have used input buttons **next** and **back** to call the image change.

How do I add a random html link so when I click on a image it goes to a different html page?

Comment: Define _"a random html link"_ and _"different html page"_ - what page do you want to link to, and in what way should it be _random_?

Comment: according to my understanding from the question..You can use a hyperlink similarly how you are using img and can give href in your javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Surround your `<img>` tag inside an `<a>` like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" id="link1"><img id="img1" src="images/img1.jpg"></a>
```

Now in both the methods add code to update the href of the  tag accordingly.

```
 var urls=["http://www.example.com","http://www.example2.com","http://www.example3.com","http://www.example4.com"];
function moveToNextSlide()
{
if (index >= 4){index=0}
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideName="images/img" + titles[++index] + ".jpg";
img.src=slideName;
var link= document.getElementById("link1");
var url=urls[++index];
link.href=url;
}

function moveToPreviousSlide()
{
if (index <= 0){index=4}
{
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideName="images/img" + titles[--index] + ".jpg";
img.src=slideName;
var link= document.getElementById("link1");
var url=urls[++index];
link.href=url;
}
}
```

Try and tell.